# How to make a check that only allows the command in server I specify

Tags: python, discord.py

I want to make a command that I only want to run in servers i want to choose, so is it possible to make a custom check that does this?

Answer (score 1):

You have to options:

```py
allowedGuilds = [some, ids, here]

# 1. Check guild id with an if statement:
@bot.command()
async def test(ctx):
    if not ctx.guild.id in allowedGuilds:
        return
    # your code

# 2. Create your own decorator:
def allowed_guild():
    def predicate(ctx):
        return ctx.guild.id in allowedGuilds

    return commands.check(predicate)


@bot.command()
@allowed_guild()
async def test(ctx):
    # your code
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use [`checks`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ext/commands/commands.html#checks) which is fairly simple when the return is True the command will procced

This will allow you to use the **same check for different commands**

> - Return `True` to signal that the person can run the command.
> - Return `False` to signal that the person cannot run the command.
> - Raise a `CommandError` derived exception to signal the person cannot run the command.
>   This allows you to have custom error messages for you to handle in the
>   error handlers.

```py
async def is_channel(ctx):
    return ctx.channel.id in [123,456]

@bot.command()
@commands.check(is_channel)
async def something(ctx):
    await ctx.send('Hey.')
```

Answer (score 0):

A simple if statment would work.

```
@bot.command()
async def yourcommand(ctx):
    guilds = [Yourguilidhere, Yourguilidhere, Yourguilidhere]
    if ctx.guild.id in guilds:
        #do the command here
    else:
        await ctx.send("You can't use this command here!")
```